# Extra parameters in a self executing function?

Tags: javascript

I saw this piece of code in a webpack compiled file

```
(1,2, function(x) {
    console.log(x);
    return 4;
})(5);
```

This seems to execute correctly. I am aware the `5` is a parameter to `function(x)`

I don't understand what the `1`,`2` are? How is this valid?

Comment: It's the comma operator: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator. The comma operator evaluates everything joined by commas and returns the result of the last thing. So `1,2,3` results in `3`. Another example `'hello', [1,2,3], 100` results in 100. So `1,2, function () {}` results in a function.

Comment: Also generally, see [what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9549780/what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-javascript), and you can go to e.g. https://astexplorer.net/ and look at the resulting AST for how expressions are parsed.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's because the brackets only returns the function

`(thing1,thing2,thing3,thing4....,thingN)` would show the last thing on the list(in this case, `thingN`)

Example

```js
var bracketTest1=(1,3,5,7,9,null)
console.log(bracketTest1) //null
var bracketTest2=(null,1,2,3,4)
console.log(bracketTest2) //4
var bracketTest3=(null,1,2,4,5,function(x){return x})
console.log(bracketTest3) //function(x)
console.log(bracketTest3(Object)) //function Object()
console.log((1,2,3,4,null,undefined)) //prints undefined
```